# Checkbox value comes in as empty string through POST in PHP

Tags: php, html, checkbox

So my html is:

```
<form action="/product/additem" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="checkbox" name="item_active" id="item_active" value="Yes" />
    *** more input types but all of them are type file & text
</form>
```

Now in my PHP I do this:

```
var_dump($_POST['item_active']);
```

and this is what I get:

```
string(0) ""
```

**NOTE:**
My javascript code that does the actual `.submit`

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
   $('#new_item_container form').submit();
});
```

What is wrong with my checkbox I dont get it. I am using **Firefox**

Comment: Why are you using "multipart/form-data" for a simple (non-multipart) form?

Comment: well its not a simple form it does file upload as well, i just posted the form part and checkbox part. It also has the `<input type="file"`in it

Comment: The only apparent question is: Did you check the check-box ?

Comment: What output do you get when you check it and execute the script? It looks like you are not checking it on submission.

Comment: If he didn't check the checkbox, `$_POST['item_active']` wouldn't be set at all.

Comment: Do you have multiple inputs with the name `item_active`?

Comment: no dont have input field with same name but I had nested forms, form within a form (not sure why), most likely a typo but once I removed nested form now it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have any other `<form>` tags ahead or around this form?  This is a shot in the dark, but I had this problem last week, and was pulling my hair out, until I found that the form I was looking at, was actually nested inside another form, and that changes the behavior.  If the other form has the same named value, it can (in some cases, apparently) take precedence and prevent you from seeing the value that you think you are getting.

Comment: Found the problem was similar to yours but this led me to a solution so thank you for that. Was nested forms problem.

Comment: If that answer helped, check it as the accepted answer.Glad it helped.

Comment: will do in 2 minutes :D